# VUEX mutations and actions in external files

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have broken my single page store into separate files.  So now I have a State.js, Getters.js, Mutations.js, Actions.js and a index.js that pulls them all together.  I've created the State.js with

```
            export default {
            memberID: '12345'
             }
```

and the getter with:

```
           export default {
           memberID: function (state) {
           return state.memberID
            }
            }
```

My problem it the syntax for the mutation and action page.  I've tried

```
            setMemberID (state, memberID) {
            state.memberID = memberID
             }
```

but that gives me an error looking for a ";" I would like to be able to do

```
           this.$store.commit('setMemberID', '54321')
```

I'm sure that I'm missing some type of wrapper.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please share more details and the error message

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to add a mutation to an external file.  I can do it in the single page store.js file the error is unexpected token ; expected

Comment: You are missing the `export default` in your mutation file.

Comment: Thank-- adding export default fixed it-